# Is there a way to prevent black frames from appearing at the start of a video when using -c:v copy?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg in terminal, I'm trying to pass through the exact video settings minus the audio, and i've been successful, except for the fact that the videos start with a frame of black before the actual video plays.

currently using this:

```
for i in *.*;do ffmpeg -i "$i" -an -c:v copy "${i%.*}_noaudio.mp4";done
```

My current thought is it may be related to the error I'm getting (the vid still exports), but I'm not certain:
Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1001

Googling led me to try not using -c:v copy as there *might* be a glitch related to h264 keyframes and instead using -c:v libx264 but i really don't want to have to re-encode as I don't want to lose any quality. The file I tried this on went from 135 mb down to 6.

Comment: It is because of that error. Videos require an I-frame in order to create the intermediate frames between I-frames. So, if an I-frame is missing, there is no image initially upon which the intermediary frames rely on to create their images.

Comment: When you re-encoded, how did the quality subjectively appear to you? If it went from 125MB to 6M, then there may be a lot of extraneous information you really didn't need (but I understand you quality concerns). Also, what was the original video codec? Lastly, if you decide to re-encode, go ahead and do it in HEVC as the compression is better.

Comment: The quality of the 6mb file was pretty terrible. Original file is XAVC h.264 from a Sony a7s III.

Comment: Given that the first I-frame is corrupt/missing, the only solution would be to skip (`-ss [seconds]`) at the start equivalent to the next I-frame. You can still use copy but you would lose the first second or less (I-frames tend to be embedded at least every second - typically). You could use `ffprobe -show_frames [file] | head -500` and scroll through the to find the first I-frame (`pict_type`) and the corresponding timestamp. (PS I think I'm using `head -500` correctly to print only the first 500 lines but its been a while).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try that.

Comment: That totally worked. `for i in *.*;do ffmpeg -ss 0.1 -i "$i" -an -c:v copy "${i%.*}_noaudio.mp4";done` did it for me and i only lost a few frames. Thanks again for your help. Been googling this for months to no avail.